# changing a class inside an ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the sample div with class name "**assistance_wrap**".

```
<div class="assistance_wrap">
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="header highlight">Types of assistance offered at this event:</div>
<div class="nearby_header highlight">This event is currently full, but there are other ways you can</div>
</div>
```

I have cloned this div and each cloned version has a unique ID attached to it.

```
<div id="assistance_wrap_315" class="assistance_wrap">
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="header highlight">Types of assistance offered at this event:</div>
<div class="nearby_header highlight">This event is currently full, but there are other ways you can</div>

<div id="assistance_wrap_316" class="assistance_wrap">
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="header highlight">Types of assistance offered at this event:</div>
<div class="nearby_header highlight">This event is currently full, but there are other ways you can</div>
```

In my JS I assign the name **new_info** to the copy of the sample div with class "assistance_wrap"
and assign unique Id to it and display on my page.
Now I want to change the text inside the class **nearby_header highlight** who's parent div id is
**assistance_wrap_316** how should I do this ?

This is what I have tried. The output of the log is basically the entire text of the div with id **assistance_wrap_316**.

```
console.log(new_info.find('#assistance_wrap_'+ event_data.eventId , '.nearby_header highlight').text());
```

Assume event_data.eventId's value is 316

Comment: if `new_info` is a copy of the div with class `assistance_wrap` then doing `new_info.find('#assistance_wrap_...` is trying to find the div within itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should remove the `","`:

```
console.log($('#assistance_wrap_'+ event_data.eventId + ' .nearby_header').text());
```

or use `find()` method:

```
console.log($('#assistance_wrap_'+ event_data.eventId).find('.nearby_header').text());
```

Comment: The output of the console is an empty string !!

Comment: @YeshwanthVenkatesh sorry there was a typo, try the updated answer.